# Dejar marcada la página del menú en la que te encuentras bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Mi pregunta es básicamente lo que dice el título. ¿Que habría de hacer para dejar marcada la opción de menú de la página en la que me encuentro?

Mi código es este:

HTML

```
 <nav class="nav-principal navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-faded">
                <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#nav-principal" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Mostrar navegacion">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <a href="index.php" class="navbar-brand d-lg-none mx-2">Accion Reaccion</a>

                <div class="col-12 mt-4">
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="nav-principal">
                        <ul class="nav nav-justified flex-column flex-sm-row">
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="index.php">Inicio</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="conocenos.php">Conócenos</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="obras.php">Obras</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="galeria.php">Galería</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="premios.php">Premios</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="contacto.php">Contacto</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div><!--div menu-->
                </div><!--div menu-->
            </nav><!--.nav-principal-->
```

Y el CSS:

```
    /** Estilos menú **/

.navegacion {
      background-color: #000000;
      position: relative;
}
.navbar-toggler {
    background-color: white;
}
@media (min-width: 575px){
    .flex-sm-row {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
.bg-faded {
    background-color: solid;
}
.navbar-brand {
    color: white!important;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
nav.nav-principal .nav-item {
    transition: background-color .5s ease-in-out;
}

nav.nav-principal .nav-item .nav-link:hover {
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 0.2rem;
    color: black;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border-bottom:0px solid white;

}

nav.nav-principal .nav-item .nav-link {
    font-size: 1rem;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding: 0rem;
    margin: 0rem;
    border-bottom:1px solid white;
}
```

Muchas gracias de antemano

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Para que los `li` en Bootstrap 4 se queden marcados hay que agregar la clase `active`, lo puedes hacer en Javascript.

Primero agregarle un `id` a los `li`

```
<li class="nav-item" id="tab-index">
    <a class="nav-link" href="index.php">Inicio</a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item" id="tab-conocenos">
     <a class="nav-link" href="conocenos.php">Conócenos</a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item" id="tab-obras">
      <a class="nav-link" href="obras.php">Obras</a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item" id="tab-galeria">
      <a class="nav-link" href="galeria.php">Galería</a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item" id="tab-premios">
      <a class="nav-link" href="premios.php">Premios</a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item" id="tab-contacto">
      <a class="nav-link" href="contacto.php">Contacto</a>
</li>
```

Luego en Javascript, a la hora de cargar la pagina hay que detectar en la pagina que estamos y asignar una clase dependiendo de ello.

```
/// Url actual
let url = window.location.href;

/// Elementos de li
const tabs = ["index", "conocenos", "obras", "galeria", "premios", "contacto"];

tabs.forEach(e => {
    /// Agregar .php y ver si lo contiene en la url
    if (url.indexOf(e + ".php") !== -1) {
        /// Agregar tab- para hacer que coincida la Id
        setActive("tab-" + e);
    }

});

/// Funcion que asigna la clase active
function setActive(id) {
    document.getElementById(id).setAttribute("class", "nav-item active");
}
```

Comment: Perfecto¡¡ Solucionado. Mil gracias¡ :)

Answer (score 4):

Tienes que añadir la clase `.active` al `li` correspondiente, pero para que te funcione te falta añadir la clase `.navbar-nav` al `ul`

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">

<nav class="nav-principal navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-faded">
  <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#nav-principal" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Mostrar navegacion">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <a href="index.php" class="navbar-brand d-lg-none mx-2">Accion Reaccion</a>

  <div class="col-12 mt-4">
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="nav-principal">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav nav-justified flex-column flex-sm-row">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="index.php">Inicio</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="conocenos.php">Conócenos</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link " href="obras.php">Obras</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="galeria.php">Galería</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="premios.php">Premios</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="contacto.php">Contacto</a>
        </li>
     </ul>
     </div><!--div menu-->
   </div><!--div menu-->
</nav><!--.nav-principal-->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-cs/chFZiN24E4KMATLdqdvsezGxaGsi4hLGOzlXwp5UZB1LY//20VyM2taTB4QvJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-uefMccjFJAIv6A+rW+L4AHf99KvxDjWSu1z9VI8SKNVmz4sk7buKt/6v9KI65qnm" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Basta con agregar a tu li una clase css para indicar que esta activa:

```
 <li class="nav-item active">
     <a class="nav-link" href="obras.php">Obras</a>
 </li>
```

Claro, tienes que detectar vía javascript o php por ejemplo en que pagina estás para colocarlo.

```
if (window.location.href.indexOf("obras.php") != -1){
//colocas la class
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes añadir el siguiente código en javascript para determinar el fichero actual cargado y marcar en consecuencia el menú asociado:

```
<script>
    var url = window.location.pathname;
    var filename = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
    $(".menu_activo").removeClass("menu_activo");
    $('.nav-link[href="' + filename + '"]').addClass("menu_activo");
</script>
```

También tienes que añadir el estilo:

```
<style>
    .menu_activo {
        background-color: #000000;
        color: #ffffff;
    }
</style>
```

Esto se puede hacer de muchas formas, también desde el propio PHP, en este caso sería hacer un if con el basename de la url para identificar el elemento de menú a marcar o en tu caso, como cada elemento de menú va a un fichero separado, solo tendrías que poner la clase a mano en cada elemento según el fichero, por ejemplo, en index.php la clase estaría en el primer elemento del menú mientras que en el fochero conocenos.php, marcarias la segunda.